# How to find strings from a list that didnt find exact matches from a file

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

The question [How to grep exact matches from a file of a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075132/how-to-grep-exact-matches-from-a-file-of-a-list-of-strings) asks how to find strings from one file (A) in another file (B), but only where the string makes up a complete field in file B. The [awk command provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075222/56541) works perfectly. But how can I see which strings from file A didn't find a match in file B?

Comment: doesn't `fgrep -v -f listFile dataFile` work? good luck.

Comment: No,    `fgrep -v -f listFile dataFile` outputs lines from dataFile (B) that was not matched with string from listFile (A). I need strings in A that didn't find match in B.

Comment: if the awk solution below doesn't solve your problem, you'll need to improve your Q with sample data, and expected output .Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{b[$1];next} !($4 in b)' B A
```

Comment: It does the same thing as the command provided by @shellter. I would like to have strings from A that didn't find match in B.

Comment: @Alexander You can change the order of input files.